# About the solutions of Paraxial Equation and Schrödinger Equation

Tags: optics, schroedinger-equation

There is an analogy between the Schrödinger Equation for a free particle:

$$
-\frac{\hslash^2}{2m} \nabla^2 \psi (x,y,t) = i\hslash \frac{\partial \psi (x,y,t)}{\partial t}
$$

and the Paraxial Helmholtz Equation, which describes collimated beams:

$$
 \nabla^2 \psi (x,y,z)= -2 i k \frac{\partial \psi (x,y,z)}{\partial z}
$$

The above equation describes a beam propagating through the "z" direction. Realize that, despite the presence of the variable "time", in non-relativistic quantum mechanics, time is not well-defined, so the "t" which appears in SE can be a free parameter, like the "z" coordinate.

It is well known some of the solutions for the PHE, and one of then is the family of polynomials Hermite-Gauss:

$$
\psi_{mn}(x,y,z) \propto H_m \bigg{(} \frac{\sqrt{2} x}{w(z)} \bigg{)} H_n \bigg{(} \frac{\sqrt{2} y}{w(z)} \bigg{)} \exp\bigg{(} - \frac{x^2 + y^2}{w(z)^2}\bigg{)}
$$

The solutions of these equations keeps its amplitude, evolving with the respective parameter (t,z) through a global phase. So... if the Hermite-Gauss is a solution of the PHE, and this has the same mathematical form of the SE for the free particle, it is correct to say that the HG modes is solution of the SE? More general: Is the space of solutions of the PHE the same as the time dependent SE (for a free particle)? Maybe it is worth to say that while the SE is "given", the PHE corresponds to the spatial part of the wave equation, with the approximation that the wave is collimated (diffraction is very "slow" at the wavelength scale). Am I missing something here?